# Can't sign out of google cloud datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am using Google Cloud datalab, although really I'm just getting started.

I need to log out and sign in as a new user and when I click sign out this does not sign me out. I check the drop down at the to right and still show as logged in.

That was from the notebook directory screen. When I try the same from a notebook the effect is the same except it warns me that I'm leaving the page first.

This is the same on my local machine and on cloud compute.

How can I sign out on datalab? Is this a bug?

**Update**

Problem recreated on separate machine, again running locally.

**Update 2**

I've since found that the application has signed out successfully, but it doesn't indicate this to be the case. It still shows that I'm signed in with my email. Now when trying to run a query it returns "No application credentials found. Perhaps you should sign in."

**Update 3**
Command used to start datalab:

```
docker run -d -it -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "${HOME}:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID={project-id}" datalab bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the folks working on the project to [respond here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1913)

Multi-login is not currently supported, but there is a work around which by their own words is:

Run this command from a cell:

```
!rm /content/datalab/.config/*
```

I assume that requires a %%bash before the ! to run. But I could actually get this work. I logged into a terminal and ran:

```
rm -r /content/datalab/.config/*
```

After this you may have to change projects which you can do with:

```
%datalab project set -p project_id
```